# Clean method of providing blank first value in Silverlight Combobox?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, combobox, wcf-ria-services

I've got a combobox in silverlight that is bound to a list of objects in XAML coming from RIA servcies.  Is there a clean method to add a blank value for the first item so that users have to click the dropdown in order to select something?  Right now, it just displays the first item, even if the selected index is set to -1.

Comment: How are you setting up the binding? If you use a SelectedItem binding or set the SelectedItem to null it should remain blank.

Comment: The binding is just to a domain data source on the same page.

Comment: @Kyle McClellan it doesn't remain blank - setting SelectedItem = null doesn not update the underlying datacontext